# ¿Como puedo obtener un nombre aleatorio contenido en un Arreglo?

Tags: java, array

Quisiera obtener un nombre aleatorio ingresado por el usuario dentro de un arreglo y mostrarlo por pantalla

```
String nombres_sorteo[]=new String[5];
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        System.out.println("Por favor ingrese nombre");
        nombres_sorteo[i]=rd.nextLine();
        
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        
        System.out.println("El nombre numero "+i+" ingresado"+ " fue " +nombres_sorteo[i]);
    }

        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método **Math.random()** como te muestro en el siguiente código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String nombres_sorteo[] = new String[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Por favor ingrese nombre");
        nombres_sorteo[i] = src.nextLine();

    }
    
    int ganador = (int) (Math.random()*5);

    System.out.println("El nombre numero " + ganador + " ingresado" + " fue " + nombres_sorteo[ganador]);

}

}
```

**Salida**:

```
run:
Por favor ingrese nombre
Pablo
Por favor ingrese nombre
Sara
Por favor ingrese nombre
Teresa
Por favor ingrese nombre
Toño
Por favor ingrese nombre
Carlos

El nombre numero 4 ingresado fue Carlos
```

Como ves, creo una variable **ganador** que es donde genero el **índice aleatorio**. Prescindo del segundo bucle for, directamente imprimo la salida indicando el número que ha salido y el nombre (para lo cual, indico al array que lea el índice ganador).

Espero haberte podido ayudar.

Comment: Muchas gracias pablo! , funciona a la perfección gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @negr0 gracias a ti! Si te ha servido de ayuda, recuerda confirmar la pregunta con el stick que hay a la izquierda de ella, por favor :)